# Start bootstrap theme not displaying correctly in Github pages

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, github-pages

I have downloaded the bootstrap greyscale theme from https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/grayscale/ 
However, it is not displaying correctly when uploaded to Github pages: https://heathbm9.github.io/test5/, works fine in local host. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing the vendor folder, check the errors in Google Chrome Console, which clearly shows what references it's trying to load.

[image: Google Chrome Console errors]

Comment: According to the repo it is there: https://github.com/heathbm9/test5 , why would it not load? I've tried with multiple repos too.

Comment: @james, it seems the link is no longer available

Answer (score 0):

GitHub Pages now uses Jekyll 3.3.0 which ignores the `vendor` directory by default. Create a `_config.yml` file and add `exclude: []` in the file as suggested in this [GitHub Blog Post](https://github.com/blog/2277-what-s-new-in-github-pages-with-jekyll-3-3).